# How to convert string(R.id.btn_0) into int type - Espresso

Tags: java, android-espresso

I want to convert string type into int. I am doing automation using espresso.

As per espresso automation syntax for clicking on object, `onView(withid(R.id.btn_0).perform(click())`

I have json file, where I have stored the object,

```
"btn_0": {
      "ANDROID": "withId=R.id.btn_0"
  }
```

Now, when I read btn_0, i get string value for the btn_0 object and withId() takes int.

Note: Integer.parseInt() will not work.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse a resource name to an integer using the `Resources.getIdentifier()` method, I have prepared an example for you:

```
@Test
public void parseResourceIdTest() {
    final Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();

    assertEquals(R.id.btn_0, parseResourceId(context, "btn_0"));
}

public static int parseResourceId(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull String string) {
    return context.getResources().getIdentifier(string, "id", context.getPackageName());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing entire ID like "R.id.modeName" only pass "modeName"

final Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
        int obj = context.getResources().getIdentifier("modeName", "id", context.getPackageName());
        onView(withId(obj)).perform(click());

Answer (score -1):

Below is work around,try this

```
   while( i < withId.length()) {
      num *= 10;
      num += withId.charAt(i++) - '0'; 

   }
```

this workarround available here please check it : [How do I convert a String to an int in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-int-in-java)

Comment: My string is not "1234". It is "R.id.btn_0" which is internally integer for espresso automation. However, @Jarosław Wiśniewski has solved my problem